# dark areas are not being rendered properly

Tags: rendering, materials, lighting

i've attached the final render of my scene, does anyone have an idea what can cause these grainy areas on dark surfaces such as the black kitchen cabinets and the glass. i rendered with 2200 samples and 2000*2300 res. global illumination

what other material or render properties should i pay attention to in order to make the scene look nice and sharp even in dark areas?
or is it lighting setting after all?
[image: my interior scene final render]

Comment: Interior renders tend to have a lot of noise, how exactly is the room lit? I see a few small lamps but I guess the main light source is an HDRI shining through the window? Does the window have glass or is it just open to let more light in? Are you using denoising?

Comment: as you can see at the comment of Gordon - you do not provide enough information to your question. So maybe for you it is the easiest way to give us all necessary information by providing your blend file.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann thank you for your answer! yes i am using an hdri with a strength of 10.000  and portal area light to the windows, i also tried to make some adjustments with the exposure and gamma but didnt want to burn the light areas. i do have windows materials, should i get rid of them? they wont be in the render frame anyway.

Comment: thank you too @Chris i just tried to attach a screen shot of my settings for the hdri, the glass and the render but dont find a way how to do it

Comment: You can add images of your settings by editing your question via the button at the bottom and then adding them as you did with your scene images. To save a screenshot of a Blender area go to Window > Save Screenshot (Editor), hover over the area and click to save the image.

Comment: @kseniazaks A window glass material can definitely create more noise than when the light shines directly into the room, and it can also absorb a lot of light, depends on how the material is set up. And the HDRI - the strength is 10 (10.000), not 10000 (10,000) if I understand it correctly? I would definitely keep the portal. However, you have to be aware that in real life, sky and sun are very, very, very bright. Real cameras adjust with aperture and exposure time, outside settings result in very dark images inside. So playing with the exposure is a way to fix it.

Comment: @kseniazaks On another question I explained a bit more in-depth and showed examples of how the settings can vary, maybe this will give you some hints on what you can try and change to get better results: [HDRI lighting too dark and HDR image just acting odd](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271730/hdri-lighting-too-dark-and-hdr-image-just-acting-odd/271740#271740)