Match real-life photo shading (stone statue)
In preparation for a shooting, I'm trying to match a 3d scan to a photo found online. The environment is 4 statues made of stone and I'm trying to match the shading and material for a future VFX shot.
My issue is that in my render, indirect lighting look way stronger than in real life (in shadowy areas). I have no idea what I could do to "reduce bounced light" or something like that. I'll explain below the exact issue.
The real-life photo

The Blender setup
My setup is quite simple :

The 3D scan as a mesh, with a generic stone texture found online
The wall behind and below it with the same stone texture and set to Indirect only
An HDRI for the world, that matches more or less the real-life photo
Render engine : Cycles
Color managment : AgX

Sadly, the most basic version of my scene is 300+MB. Too big for blend-exchange. Here is a version without packed resources.


My current result and the issue
For now, I have this result :

Which isn't too bad for a preview, but unsatisfactory. Here is the issue I'm facing.

In the photo, the surroundings of the shadows don't look to give much indirect light to shadows. It looks like the light in shadows mainly comes from the environment (e.g. sky). It is almost uniform, like a version of the shader of the stone just darkened a bit.
In my render, the shadows are heavily brightened up by the indirect light. We clearly see the indirect light coming from below. In addition to that, the indirect light seems more colored than in the photo (it may be just because of indirect light being brighter).
Note that my issue isn't about changing the exposure of the shadow areas. The issue isn't about the intensity of indirect light, rather it is about the distribution of indirect light in these areas. Indirect light from surrounding stone being too strong compared to the global indirect light in the scene.
Current solution
For now, the only thing I've found that helps is to reduce the saturation in dark areas with the following nodes :

It does improve a bit the situation, but still the indirect light from near the shadows looks way stronger. So it's not really solving my issue.

My question
What could be the reasons for such difference between real-life and my render ? What way should I go to improve the matchiness of my render ? Is there something obvious that would improve the situation ? Like change HDRI, change material, change exposure+lights, ...
My final goal is only to match the photo, anything else can be subject to change if needed.
Many thanks for your time !

maybe your material is too reflective / too smooth? or maybe your sun light is not powerful enough.

@Luciano Thank you. The roughness is already set to 1, and I can't really just turn up the sun lights otherwise I have to darken the stone texture to compensate. The result would be identical.

Real life light and shadows can't be replicated 100% in 3D by one light source only, in order to get more realistic light, you need to add some elements to make you get the result. To replicate one light bulb real life light, you probably going to need more than two or three light sources to get the same light in 3D, there are other elements that could also help, like Ambient Occlusion. When you do 3D Light and HDRI is a good starting point, but not enough

@Emir Are you implying that my HDRI is too different from real-life, and that if I capture an HDRI on-location, it should match perfectly ? The shooting not having taken place yet, it would be a great info to have before-hand. So thank you :)

Actually the opposite, even If you have the HDRI from the exact location, doesn't meant that only that should be you light, to match the 3D object with the real life one. The HDRI from the same location is a good start and from there tweak your light with other thing, as mentioned, Ambient occlusion is one of those, a light source placed in some specific areas and so, lastly, try to color correct your scene

@Lutzi Actually Luciano is not totally wrong, the Sun at noon has a strength around 1000 W/m² (the unit Blender's sun lamp uses as well), so to get "realistic" lighting you could set the Strength to 1000. The thing is that our eyes can adapt to this and real cameras adjust aperture, shutter speed and ISO to not have everything blown out. So maybe when you adjust your scene to get the stone exposed correctly with that sun, the shadows might be more correct, too. But the render engine does not work exactly like real cameras, a render has no shutter speed, ISO or aperture to adjust exposure.

@GordonBrinkmann Do you think I should also go into a 1000 range for HDRI strength (HDRI with a direct sun of course) ? Thank you all for your comments ! Super interesting, I'm gonna do some more test.

@Lutzi Well no, not really. As I said, the adjustments you can make on a real camera are different than what you can do in Blender, also our eyes and brains have different ways of adaptation. But if you are going for realistic results you can either try many ways of faking it with multiple lights etc. like mentioned earlier by Emir or make a bright sun (not 1000, but 10 or more) and adjust exposure, contrast etc. The problem is, in reality light bounces around countless times, but you cannot set so many bounces and samples to simulate it if you want your render to finish one day

I cannot say I have a definitive solution for you. To get something exactly like reality just by trying to make it close to reality is hardly possible, since you cannot get all relevant factors exactly like reality. Anyway, maybe just for information, here is an answer I once wrote where someone had a problem with the lighting of his HDRI for an interior scene. There I show examples how you can get more realistic results without additional light sources or fake glass to let more light in: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/271730/hdri-lighting-too-dark-and-hdr-image-just-acting-odd

@Lutzi Your lightning is over lighted ... in your scene you are combining indirect lighting by simplified statue model with texture that is already containing light + environmental light (HDRi) and all of that on a 3D scan model that use a texture also already lighted even before mentioned light sources hit a model surface... so those are like 3 light sources used on final result. It interest me, but  can give you answer later evening if it still fits to your schedule :) ... BTW there is an addon Real Camera, that is made for easier transferring real camera parameters to blenders envi.

@vklidu I have at least 2 weeks before the shooting. My texture isn't containing light, it's a pack texture from AmbientCG (color, displacement, AO). The 3d model is only a mesh with no texture. So, none of the 3 light sources you are talking about. Thanks for your time !

What you were described in comment above is not what I see in your .blend file (and what I can see from your screens) and what I see in your blend is what I see on your screens ... so there is some misunderstanding :)

@vklidu The mesh is a 3D scan, the material is a separate multi-file stone texture. I've updated the corresponding part of my question.

That is not the point, but leave it :) Comment section here is on a way to be moved into chat room (since chatting is not allowed here) ... so maybe it will be more clear from my planed answer. But if you are using specific texture that we should match, it make sense to share it too (HDRi and backplate I already downloaded from a net) ... BTW this is a location of shooting or you are looking at a general workflow. Thanks

@vklidu No specific texture, I just need to match the shot. This is indeed the location of shooting and general placement of camera. But no idea what camera has taken the photo, in our case we'll use a Sony A7S III (s-log3.cine).

In general - the issue you mentioned is problem of indirect distribution, you already know that. Shadow under crossed hands if fine, so problem come from bottom indirect rays (or HDRi side) ... you could try to eliminate it in shader. Also highlights in your render are darker (thanks to color management that is trying keep color range wider, some Look-Contrast could help). Anyway, instead of playing with all the color profiles and high dynamic ranges to restore non-existing light  condition ... it seems to me straight forward for this purpose to just fake it :)
Cycles
At the end the setup is simple as hell ... there is not much to share ...
Here I used:

Sun - Strength 3,5
World - grey color 0.3
Color Management - sRGB - Standard
Material - is just image texture (sRGB) pluged into Diffuse shader

All the light adjustment is happening between World grey value and Sun strength (alternatively you can also use RGB Curve node behind image Texture node).

To better control indirect floor light I deleted all back wall floor faces and set solo material to back plate catching shadow of 3Dscan on the wall, but can be shadow catcher as well.

Sidenotes
I dont know what is your shooting story, but make it better integrated next to the statue figures, consider generate depth map (even as image sequence) used for displace rather than 3D model, because statue is kind of bass-relief so shape characteristics and light behaviour works a bit differently.



For more advanced integration I would take 360 equirectangular image at shooting location, that can be used as environment and source of light and like shadow catcher like in this video ... under the video is a link to BA for more info or here Shader for HDRi envi ... currently part of addon Photographer
Or reconstruct scene from 360 HDRi

Thank you ! It's super interesting seeing another setup. I have a hard time appreciating Eevee but I reckon your answer is already better than mine.

@Lutzi ... Just if you noticed the update to Cycles version ... Did it solve your issue?

I was able to get the same result as yours (material and lighting), with a sun light and a world emission just like you. I took a few pictures of the environment for reconstruction but didn't even need it to use it. In the meantime, I realised I could also separate the indirect pass to better tweak it if needed. Thanks again for you answer !

The look of your bas-relief is awesome viewed from the front ! Sadly in my shot, we see the statue from a 45° angle, so the backside doesn't look good. But still, it helps me see what I could change on the statue to better match the original style.

Great it helps ... sure you know the best what will work for you. Good luck with your project :)
